# Infinite loop in page redirection

Tags: algorithm, testing, computer-science, infinite-loop, software-design

We keep developing different pages for internal use and some pages may redirect to the others. Suppose that the company goes bigger, pages are becomming more and more. Is there a way to detect redirection loop among those pages?

Comment: you can use something like Screaming Frog that will do a Website Scan and report you any error, and it will test every link that finds in any page, so you give it the homepage, and probably all the website will be tested (heuristically speaking)... i'm doing this things with it, and so far it has worked fine as far as i know

Answer (score 0):

Construct a graph with a node for each page, and a directed edge from node A to node B if page A redirects to page B.

Then your problem is the classic problem to find a cycle in a directed graph. This is solved using Tarjan's *strongly connected components* algorithm, where each strongly connected component of size > 1 implies a cycle between those pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass around in query parameters the redirection breadcrumbs, checking at each redirect whether the page you're redirecting to has already appeared in the breadcrumbs previously:

```
breadcrumbs = querystring["breadcrumbs"].split("-")
if not breadcrumbs.contains(targetpageid) then
    redirect(targetpageurl + "?breadcrumbs=" + querystring["breadcrumbs"] + "," +  mypageid)
```

It might even make sense to adjust the above so that the first page to appear twice in the breadcrumbs terminates the redirect loop, so that each page only needs to know its own page id (and not the page ids of its targets). Of course, if the redirect URLs might differ only by query parameters, you'll need different page IDs for every combination of parameters you might redirect for; in that case, it could make sense to perhaps hash the URL (excluding the breadcrumbs parameter) and use that hash as the page ID. You can probably get away with a relatively short hash provided the function doesn't produce too many collisions.

If you're concerned about the user seeing the big ugly breadcrumbs string on the final page (once the redirects stop) you can also make your pages detect no further redirects, and then redirect to themselves without the breadcrumbs parameter. You could take the absence of a breadcrumbs parameter to mean that the page must not redirect or you could have the page redirect to itself with a breadcrumbs string set just to its own pageid. If you use the modification mentioned above to have pages halt the loop when they detect themselves in the breadcrumbs twice, this will work and users will just see a single page id - the one for the page they're looking at.

Obviously, putting the breadcrumb information in the query string allows the end user to override the behavior and effectively prevent or allow redirects. If you don't want to allow this, you can keep the breadcrumbs information in the back end (a database, redis, etc.) and just pass around a session in the query string. Each redirect will use the session key to look up the breadcrumbs, and the system works more or less the same way as described above.

You could even make the system notify an administrator when this occurs by writing a log somewhere or sending an email. This could be helpful if you do not want loops and the goal is to remove them when they are discovered rather than simply preventing infinite redirects at runtime by breaking loops that do exist.